# Still getting JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type error even JSON response is ok

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

Ive been following a tutorial in:  [Androidhive](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)
Connect Android with PHP, MySQL

but trying out the piece of codes, I got these problems, Ive modified the php files coz im getting JSON response errors,

here is the code for php:

```
<?php
 header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
 /*
  * Following code will create a new product row
  * All product details are read from HTTP Post Request
  */
 error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
  // array for JSON response
 $response = array();

  // check for required fields
  if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['price']) &&    isset($_POST['description'])) {

$name = $_POST['name'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$description = $_POST['description'];

// include db connect class
require_once  '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// mysql inserting a new row
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO products(name, price, description) VALUES('$name', '$price', '$description')");

// check if row inserted or not
if ($result) {
    // successfully inserted into database
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // failed to insert row
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
 } else {
// required field is missing
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
 }
?>
```

and the response in postman:

```
{
"success": 1,
"message": "Product successfully created."
}
```

and here is the NewProductActivity class

```
  package com.example.androidhive;

 import java.util.ArrayList;     
 import java.util.List;

 import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
 import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
 import org.json.JSONException;
 import org.json.JSONObject;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.ProgressDialog;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.AsyncTask;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;

 public class NewProductActivity extends Activity {

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
EditText inputName;
EditText inputPrice;
EditText inputDesc;

// url to create new product
private static String url_create_product = "http://192.168.1.9/android_connect/create_product.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_product);

    // Edit Text
    inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
    inputPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
    inputDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

    // Create button
    Button btnCreateProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreateProduct);

    // button click event
    btnCreateProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // creating new product in background thread
            new CreateNewProduct().execute();
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Create new product
 * */
class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewProductActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Creating product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String name = inputName.getText().toString();
        String price = inputPrice.getText().toString();
        String description = inputDesc.getText().toString();

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", price));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                "POST", params);

        // check log cat fro response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully created product
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllProductsActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // closing this screen
                finish();
            } else {
                // failed to create product
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
 }
```

and Still I get these errors on the logcat:

```
08-26 12:47:06.078: E/JSON Parser(7304): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
08-26 12:47:06.088: E/AndroidRuntime(7304): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
08-26 12:47:06.088: E/AndroidRuntime(7304): Process: com.example.androidhive, PID: 7304
08-26 12:47:06.088: E/AndroidRuntime(7304): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
08-26 12:47:06.088: E/AndroidRuntime(7304):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
08-26 12:47:06.088: E/AndroidRuntime(7304):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
08-26 12:47:06.088: E/AndroidRuntime(7304):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
08-26 12:47:06.088: E/AndroidRuntime(7304):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
08-26 12:47:06.088: E/AndroidRuntime(7304):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
08-26 12:47:06.088: E/AndroidRuntime(7304):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
08-26 12:47:06.088: E/AndroidRuntime(7304):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
08-26 12:47:06.088: E/AndroidRuntime(7304): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-26 12:47:06.088: E/AndroidRuntime(7304):     at com.example.androidhive.NewProductActivity$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(NewProductActivity.java:99)
08-26 12:47:06.088: E/AndroidRuntime(7304):     at com.example.androidhive.NewProductActivity$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(NewProductActivity.java:1)
08-26 12:47:06.088: E/AndroidRuntime(7304):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
08-26 12:47:06.088: E/AndroidRuntime(7304):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
08-26 12:47:06.088: E/AndroidRuntime(7304):     ... 3 more
08-26 12:47:06.578: E/WindowManager(7304): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.androidhive.NewProductActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41d25ac8 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-259,114} that was originally added here
08-26 12:47:06.578: E/WindowManager(7304):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:388)
08-26 12:47:06.578: E/WindowManager(7304):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
08-26 12:47:06.578: E/WindowManager(7304):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
08-26 12:47:06.578: E/WindowManager(7304):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
08-26 12:47:06.578: E/WindowManager(7304):  at com.example.androidhive.NewProductActivity$CreateNewProduct.onPreExecute(NewProductActivity.java:76)
08-26 12:47:06.578: E/WindowManager(7304):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
08-26 12:47:06.578: E/WindowManager(7304):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
08-26 12:47:06.578: E/WindowManager(7304):  at com.example.androidhive.NewProductActivity$1.onClick(NewProductActivity.java:56)
08-26 12:47:06.578: E/WindowManager(7304):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4508)
08-26 12:47:06.578: E/WindowManager(7304):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18675)
08-26 12:47:06.578: E/WindowManager(7304):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-26 12:47:06.578: E/WindowManager(7304):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-26 12:47:06.578: E/WindowManager(7304):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-26 12:47:06.578: E/WindowManager(7304):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
08-26 12:47:06.578: E/WindowManager(7304):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-26 12:47:06.578: E/WindowManager(7304):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-26 12:47:06.578: E/WindowManager(7304):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
08-26 12:47:06.578: E/WindowManager(7304):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
08-26 12:47:06.578: E/WindowManager(7304):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and here is my JSONParser class:

```
package com.example.androidhive;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }           


    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
}
```

Comment: Check that you are not echoing the html doctype inside the db_connect.php file

Comment: GOT these: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 3 of the JSON data

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can get response by below way;

```
String success =  json.getString("success");
```

and then match success with value "1";

```
 if (success.matches("1")) {
            // successfully created product
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllProductsActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

            // closing this screen
            finish();
        } else {
            // failed to create product
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you got an HTML page back rather than a JSON object, so the JSON parser cannot parse it and throw an error. Try to make a normal HTTP call within your android app and see what you get.

Comment: yes, thats why I modified the php code by add the application/json header because the response is not in json format

Comment: @SicnarfOmsare I mean it looks like the server still respond with an HTML page after you add the content type. The error says the String starts with <!DOCTYPE, which is probably an HTML

Comment: @SicnarfOmsare so you confirmed it is related to MySQL calls? If postmon got you right response, it should not be a problem with MySQL. Try to make a regular HTTP call within your app and see what you get in your log. It should get you some error code and additional information for debugging

Comment: Ive changed to Mysqli, does respond with proper json format on postman but still getting same error again, I think there might be a problem on the server side..